# Close an HTA when the user presses the 'Esc' key

Tags: vbscript, hta, onkeyup

I'm trying to capture key presses so that I can close my HTA when the user presses the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key.

I have confirmed that the `onKeyUp` event works (I also capture the length of an input), and also that the example below is not working (by adding a `MsgBox` which is not fired).

What am I missing here?

```
Sub window_onKeyUp()

    If window.event.keyCode = 27 Then
        Call CloseHTA()
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me.

```
<script language="VBScript">
    Sub TestKey()
        intKeyCode = Window.Event.Keycode
        If intKeyCode = 27 Then Window.Close
    End Sub
</script>

<body onkeyup="TestKey">
</body>
```

**Edit:**

Alternatively, you can use `Document_OnKeyUp()` if you want to include your code after the `<body>` tag.

```
<body>
</body>

<script language="VBScript">
    Sub Document_OnKeyUp()
        intKeyCode = Window.Event.Keycode
        If intKeyCode = 27 Then Window.Close
    End Sub
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, that does work but it means that I have to include a separate `<script>` block just for this function.  Is there no way to declare it as an event within VBS?  Things like `window_onLoad` and `window_onBeforeUnload` work fine.

Comment: Why not just add `Sub TestKey()` to an existing script block? I was just showing it this way for completeness.

Comment: All my blocks are in the footer of the document.  An initial page is displayed and then the code works it's magic, and because I manipulate the display (show/hide divs, change background colour, etc.), this code has to be declared after the HTML, otherwise it fails.

Comment: I see. Yes, you can use `Document_OnKeyUp()` instead. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thank you, that's perfect. I'd tried `document.body_onKeyUp()` (error) and also setting an object `Set docBody = doucment.body`, `docBody_onKeyUp()` (didn't work), but didn't think of this blindingly simple solution!

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this :

```
<html>
<script language="VBScript">
    Sub TestKey()
        intKeyCode = Window.Event.Keycode
        If intKeyCode = 27 Then Call CloseHTA()
    End Sub
    Sub CloseHTA()
        self.close
    End Sub
</script>

<body onkeyup="TestKey">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You've got two closing `</script>` tags there.

Comment: I got what you meant though, thanks for taking the time to answer.